# Retag [libavcodec] and [libavformat] into [libav]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [libav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libav) tag description says:

> libav (or libav*) is the collective name of the FFmpeg libraries: **libavcodec**, **libavformat**, libavfilter, libavutil, etc. The name has also been appropriated by the Libav project–a fork of FFmpeg

Here is a Venn diagram of the number of question with each tags:
[image: ven diagram of question with concerned tags]

Among the question that have [libavcodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libavcodec) tag, those that only have this tag are not in majority.
Same with [libavformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libavformat).

Based on that, I think that [libavcodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libavcodec) and [libavformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libavformat) tags should be replaced by [libav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libav) then removed.

Comment: I guess the real question is whether it makes sense to keep around the individual library names over the umbrella name

Comment: +1 for a venn diagram